# PHP does not always display an error when there is clearly an error

Tags: php

I'm experiencing a weird issue where errors are not being displayed when there are obvious errors.

This throws an error as expected:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

hurrrrr

?>
```

However, this does not and just returns a blank page...

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

HUUURRRR

include('../includes/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('www.hurrrr.com');
foreach($html->find('.Hurrrrrrr') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br />';
}


?>
```

Comment: Syntax errors will lead to scripts not being interpreted at all. Not even the first line of it.

Comment: I totally love you name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is run in two main "passes".

1. Parse the code.
2. Run the code.

If the code cannot be parsed (`hurrrrr`), then it cannot be run.
If it cannot be run, then `display_errors` and `error_reporting` cannot be set.
If they cannot be set, then errors cannot be shown.

This is why it is preferable to set these in your `php.ini` file (or whatever configuration file is used for your setup). Indeed `display_startup_errors` cannot be set via `ini_set()` because by the time `ini_set` is called, startup has already finished!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Both examples should result in code that cannot being parsed but in the first example I get "Notice: Use of undefined constant HUUURRRR - assumed 'HUUURRRR' in /var/www/test.php on line 12"

Comment: This error should be reflected in the webserver logs though; and running a `php -l` against the file will also identify the error

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  This was really helpful.  I did not know I could do php -l.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the display_errors settings in `php.ini`.

If you are in localhost and use WAMP, right-clicking on WAMP icon and selecting `php.ini` may not solve your problem, as you should go to your `wamp/bin/php*/php.ini` and change this file.